# Fill-in-the-Blank Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell

How do I write a shell script that will ask a question and then store the answer in a variable? I am using bash in OS X.
Basically, this is what I want to do:

```
What is your name? (prompt for a name)
You entered: (and the name that the user entered)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into [read](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html).

Untested code:

```
echo "What is your name?"
read name
echo "You entered: $name"
```

Comment: You can set the prompt like this: `read -p "What is your name? " name`

Answer (score 2):

How about...

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/echo -n "What is your name? "
read name
/bin/echo "You said $name"
```

Comment: Yeah, I didn't reload before posting.  Sorry for the dupe.  Only one subtle difference in using `/bin/echo -n` - it doesn't append a newline.  So you get `Your name? [cursor]` as opposed to `Your name? [newline][cursor]`.   Still, he got first post.  :)

Comment: Oh...right, I would have added that anyway. Thanks so much for your help. @gpojd Thanks for your help too!